# Ubuntu Download for Intel System

Tags: installation, 13.10, intel

I am running an intel built machine but the 13.10 download file has AMD on it. Will this cause me any issues when trying to install 13.10 on the machine?

Is there an Intel specific download?

Thank you.

Comment: amd in the file name is not the company but the general name for a 64 bit system (it is named amd since they created that system ;) )

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't, you may mean amd-64.iso file , it is for all 64-bit systems. (No problem)